# How to resolve Swiperjs Fade Effect loop bug

Tags: javascript, swiper.js, slide

I am using swiper js according to their API. There are a total of 5 slides, but an error occurs without going directly from the 4th slide to the 5th slide. The 4th slide is divided into 2 times and the 5th slide is not shown and it goes to the 1st slide.

```
<div class= "swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="./images/img01-2.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="./images/img01-5.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="./images/img01-3.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="./images/img01-1.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="./images/img01-4.png" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

```
            const slideOption1 = {
                effect: 'fade',
                speed: 400,
                slidesPerView: 'auto',
                autoplay: {
                    delay: 400,
                    disableOnInteraction: false,
                },
                // loop:true,
                loopedSlides: 5,
                loopAdditionalSlides: 5,
            };
```

i tried to

```
            s1.on('slideChange', function() {
                if(s1.realIndex == 3) {
                    s1.slideToLoop(5,400)
                }
            })
```